# Font Awesome icons v5 not working with ng-class, ng-show, ng-hide in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, font-awesome

Version 5 of Font Awesome icons do not respond to changes in scope in `ng-class` / `ng-show` / `ng-hide` atributes, when using the CDN recomended in Font Awesome site: https://fontawesome.com/get-started

```
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
```

Here is a Plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/j50KjF?p=preview

And here is a post with a Plunker saying the opposite, but instead of using the recomended way of including Font Awesome, he is linking to a Font Awesome CSS file:

```
<link href="//use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/dflg0w9NPfgnSjWBeqa0?p=preview

I'm a bit confused with this. Which is the way to go to include Font Awesome icons in an AngularJS application?